# Is there any way to save a https response in a varable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, https

I'm working right now with the GitHub APi, node.js in JavaScript and the https module. I need to get the total number of commits from a repository. There is no variable that says the number of it, so I'm trying to get all the commits and just count it, but I need to iterate over them, because they are paginated

Im trying to get data from the gitHub api in a function and trying to save in a local variable, but when the request ends the variable is void . I've tried to save the data in a global variable, in a variable declared before the function, trying to save it on a local file. But Im not able to get the information.
Also I tried to return the data in the function, but I could not

```
    function getCommits(repository){
     let options {
          host: host,
           path: '/repos/'...
      }
     let request = https.request(options , (response) => {
            let body = '';
            response.on('data', (out) => {
                body += out;
                  } 
            });

     response.on('end', (out) => {
                json = JSON.parse(body);
                var i = json.length //This is the variable that I need to get out 
                                    //  from the function

            });
    }
```

The variable is undefined or is just the same value as I declared in the beginning

Comment: Partial duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323).  The second part of this question would be how to persistent store the count across requests.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mix of issues going on.  For starters, I'd recommend you read this answer [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323) as it should help you to understand some of the issues with returning a value that was retrieved asynchronously (can only be returned via callback or promise).

Then, I'd suggest using the request-promise library instead of plain `http.request()` because it's both higher level (accumulates the entire response for you), will automatically parse to JSON and it supports a promise interface which will be really useful in looping for each page.

Then, we'll use `async` and `await` to make a loop using asynchronous operations a lot simpler.

And, lastly, you don't show exactly how a loop over all the pages would work, so I'll just give you some pseudo-code for that and you will have to fill in the real implementation for github.

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

async function getAllCommits(baseURL) {
    // init counter
    let totalCommits = 0;

    // page number counter
    let pageNum = 0;

    // loop until we break out
    while (true) {
        // request desired page, auto parse JSON response
        try {
            // make github request, putting page in query string
            // the exact request is pseudo-code here, you have to construct
            // the desired URL you need for your specific request
            let data = await rp({uri: baseURL, json: true, qs: {page: pageNum++}});
        } catch(e) {
            // have to decide what to do about an error here (continue, abort, etc..)
            // for now, I'll just stop further processing, assuming you've requested
            // a page beyond what exists
            // But, this needs a more real error handling strategy based on what
            // github returns
            console.log(e);
            if (real error) {
                // stops further promising, rejects async promise
                throw e;
            } else {
                // breaks out of while loop
                break;
            }
        }
        // now iterate over the data and update the totalCommits variable

    }
    return totalCommits;
}

// sample usage
getAllCommits("http://somehost/someRepository").then(total => {
    console.log(total);
}).catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Some things you might not know about the `getAllCommits()` implmentation:

1. It's an `async` function which always returns a promise and it resolves that promise with whatever value you return from that function.
2. If you `throw` in an `async` function that will reject the returned promise with the exception value as the rejection reason.
3. Only `async` functions can use `await`.
4. `await` pauses the internal execution of the function until the promise you are awaiting resolves or rejects.
5. `await` only does something useful when awaiting a promise.
6. If the promise you are awaiting resolves successfully, you will get a value from the `await` statement.
7. If the promise you are awaiting rejects, it will essentially `throw` and the way to catch that error is to use `try/catch` with similar syntax to synchronous exceptions.
8. An `async` function pauses it's internal execution for `await` statements, but upon the first `await`, it immediately returns a promise to the outside world and the outside world continues to run your Javascript.  So, an `async` function does not pause your whole sequence of execution, just the internals of the `async` function.
9. This means that the result of an `async` function is a promise and the caller must either use `await` on that promise or `.then()` on that promise to get the returned result.

Answer (score -1):

Try writing this,  the `on()` function will return the value of length and then we are return that value from the function.

```
return response.on('end', (out) => {
   json = JSON.parse(body);
   return json.length;  
});
```

Comment: This won't return a value from the function.  You're just returning a value from an event handler.  The return value just goes back into the event handler.  It's not returned from the main function.

Comment: It doesn't work, when I try to call the function it returns "undefined"

Comment: Also, if this would work, the OP's own code would work as well.

Comment: oh yes, its inside another function which is in the event handlers callback, Thanks @jfriend00 for this. I appreciate :D